# AppInventor Trouble! (JSON-Indexing)

Tags: android, json, app-inventor

So what i partially achieved was to set an app that gets JSON text from a weather website of this form:

```
    {
"base": "stations",
"clouds": {
    "all": 20
},
"cod": 200,
"coord": {
    "lat": 40.94,
    "lon": 24.41
},
"dt": 1513711200,
"id": 735861,
"main": {
    "humidity": 100,
    "pressure": 1027,
    "temp": 274.15,
    "temp_max": 274.15,
    "temp_min": 274.15
},
"name": "Kavala",
"sys": {
    "country": "GR",
    "id": 5684,
    "message": 0.0039,
    "sunrise": 1513662178,
    "sunset": 1513695412,
    "type": 1
},
"visibility": 10000,
"weather": [
    {
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02n",
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds"
    }
],
"wind": {
    "deg": 51.0029,
    "speed": 3.07}}
```

decodes it into a list and store the results in some labelboxes in the app.The values i want to use from this JSON are:

> ("main": {"temp":}, "weather": {"main":}, "main": {"humidity":}, "wind":{"speed}".

I have managed to that quite efficiently using the integrated json decode function and indexing from App Inventor.

***Photo of Block Code:*** 
[image]

***(SCREEN RED POINTER is supposed to be "weather": {"main":} value)***

My problem is that for some cities(the app searches for data from the city name the user enters) the indexes for "weather": {"main":} and "wind":{"speed}" are different.***Is there any way i can set up a check routine for this problem?***

> For example, for  "weather": {"main":} the usual indexing as it can be seen in my code(image) is 11 2 1 4 2 of the created list.For the cities that have different index and respond with an error i think its 10 2 1 4 2.

OBJECTIVE:So what i want to do is find a way to check if the element on the  11 2 1 4 2 exists so i can use it,else look for the element with indexes 10 2 1 4 2 to use.

***UPDATE:OBJECTIVE COMPLETE DESPITE THE JSON deformity 2 dependent look up in pairs fixed the issue!***

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested **select list item** blocks as you are doing currently...
The better approach is to use the **loopup in pairs** block and the sequence of the data will not be important anymore...

[How does the lookup in pairs block work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2lookupinpairs)
[image]

**Further links**

- JSON and list of lists: [example1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/OGSe2a3X0fk/sVL8Adh1MHkJ) and [example2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/O5XpZEpM7zY/RlfTPifnCQAJ)
- [Easy to decode large information with JSON format](https://community.thunkable.com/t/easy-to-decode-large-information-with-json-format/6132?u=taifun) by Carlos
- [A general purpose JSON browser routine](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/_vk0JoHIYwI/DWikq3wGIpMJ) by ABG
- [JSON Tools Extension](https://thunkableblocks.blogspot.com.au/2017/07/jsontools-extension.html) by LukeGackle

Comment: Hey there,thanks for the quick reply.I know lookup in pairs is a way better approach,as you can see i did use it for the other variables the reason i used nested select item blocks is that on the "weather" list i get an error when using lookup.If i remember correct its something like "weather(list) is not a well formed list of pairs" or something similar.The "temperature" and "humidity" lookup in pairs blocks are working."Wind Speed" the same when the index (12 2) is right.What concerns me more is the check up routine i need to create and if its possible.Thanks again!